# NodeJS stopped working after changing version

Tags: node.js, nvm

I was working on Node version 9.1.0 but the client asked me to use NVM so that the version can be switched at will. I tried but it was not working. So I uninstalled NodeJS from my windows machine and did a fresh install of NodeJS version 8.9.4

After npm install when I tried to execute the code I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NodeJS_APIs\api\node_modules\lodash\isFunction.js:1:80)
```

The line that trew the error is in vm.js:

```
function createScript(code, options) {
  return new Script(code, options);//This is the line
}
```

I don't understand what went wrong. Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From your error stacktrace it seems the error is related to your `loadash` library, Can you please try uninstalling it using,

```
npm uninstall lodash
```

And then reinstall a compatible lodash version like this,

```
npm install lodash@4.17.5
```

Once done, try running your script again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. You are right. I did the same and the exception vanished but now the same exception is occurring for other modules as well. If I uninstall and install the module the exception arises for another one. Do I need to keep uninstalling/installing these modules? Is there any other way rather than installing modules one by one. Although I could see these modules in node_modules folder and in package.json

Comment: @user1640256 Perhaps, you can delete your `node_modules` directory and do a `npm install` afresh to get rid of these errors. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some hints from here, although I’m not sure: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2054